# How to list schemas in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema, database-schema

How to fetch a list of schema from the current database. The result which we get using \dn. This query fetches all schema

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
ORDER BY table_schema,table_name;
```

But I want only the schema which is defined in the current database. 
And then how to fetch all tables corresponding to that particular schema?

Comment: That query **will** give you the schemas of the current database

Comment: This query (SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables ORDER BY table_schema,table_name;) gives me all default schemas also. I want only my created schema from current database

Comment: What do you mean with "default schemas"?

Comment: like pg_toast, pg_internal, pg_temp_1,pg_catalog,public,information_schema.. and i have only public and myank_sing named schema in my current database. I'm getting only this two schemas when I run \dn, which is correct

Comment: Then add `where table_schema not in (...)` to your query

Comment: Of course you can: `where table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'pg_temp_1', 'information_schema', 'public', 'pg_internal');`

Answer (score 3):

several points:

1. If you want to see what query is used for psql  shortcut, run `psql -E` (with -E key)
2. `select *from pg_namespace` will give you list of schemas
3. `select * from pg_class limit where relnamespace = 'your_schema'::regnamespace` will give you all schema relations
4. `select * from pg_class limit where relnamespace = 'your_schema'::regnamespace and relkind = 'r'` will limit the list to tables only
5. to limit list of schemas to owned ones only, use

   ```
   select *from pg_namespace where nspowner = current_user::regrole;
   ```

Comment: select *from pg_namespace will give me all schema I want the schema name related to current database only. I database which I'm currently connected and not the defaults one also.

Comment: no its not. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html

Comment: if i run that i'm getting pg_toast, pg_internal, pg_temp_1,pg_catalog,public,information_schema, myank_sing but i want only public and myank_sing which i got using \dn

Comment: then run the query you see with `psql -E` (point one in my answer)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM pg_namespace` *will give you list of schemas* ... isn't that `\dn+`?

Comment: yes, `\dn` is a `psql` meta-command - very comfortable

Answer (score 0):

These list all schemas including system's in the current database:

```
\dnS
```

```
\dn *
```

These list all schemas including system's in the current database in detail:

```
\dnS+
```

```
\dn+ *
```

This lists all schemas excluding system's in the current database:

```
\dn
```

This lists all schemas excluding system's in the current database in detail:

```
\dn+
```

These also list all schemas including system's in the current database:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_namespace;
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata;
```